# Sqlite: SqliteDatabase.delete() vs a raw query

Tags: android, sqlite

**Conclusion:**  Android's database APIs *work* but the documentation is horribly incomplete.

---

I have recently run into a brain wrecking situation due to the flexibility Sqlite provides by not forcing you to specify the data type when creating the table. The problem was my mindset that assumed that every data type would be a general character sequence if not specified and therefore the way to talk to database is through `java.lang.String`.

But you can't blame me either when you see methods like the below:

```
int delete (String table, 
                String whereClause, 
                String[] whereArgs)
```

in the `SqlDatabase` class from [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

I have a table consisting of **Phone No**(that I stored as `java.lang.String`) and **Timestamp** as a long field. When I tried deleting a record using this method, it just never got deleted despite countless debugging.

I checked everything and query was alright and table is existent and all the checklist until by chance, I discovered that removing the '' around the timestamp while querying in a raw manner instead of using the above method yields a successful deletion, something like this:

```
DELETE FROM messages_records_table WHERE messageTimestamp = 1508494606000;
```

instead of the following:

```
DELETE FROM messages_records_table WHERE messageTimestamp = '1508494606000';
```

or,

```
DELETE FROM messages_records_table WHERE messageTimestamp = "1508494606000";
```

Phone No isn't a problem; it's the timestamp that was creating the problem in INSERTION/DELETION

So, I tried running a raw deletion query with quotes removed(that are required with a string/varchar type) and it yielded successful deletion. I used the following method for this:

```
db.execSQL(String sql, Object[] whereArgs)
```

The key thing to notice here is that `Object[]` is different from `String[]` when compared to `delete()`. I passed a Long to Object to make it work but passing a `Long.toString()` in `delete()` seems to be useless.

So my question is, Is my analysis correct and `delete()` API is basically useless or have I missed some bigger picture..after all, it's provided by Android team carefully?

Comment: Can you include the actual code used for the `delete`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite supports [multiple data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); and while column types are not strictly enforced, values might be automatically converted in some cases (this is called [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity)).

When your values are stored as numbers, you should access them as numbers, not as strings.

The Android database API does not allow you to use parameter types other than strings in most functions. This is a horrible design bug.

To search for a number, either use `execSQL()`, which allows you to use number parameters, or convert the string value back into a number:

```java
db.delete(..., "timestamp = CAST(? AS NUMBER)",
          new String[]{ String.valueOf(ts) });
```

Comment: Bravo! That solved the problem. That gives me motivation to explore more of SQlite caveats. Can't believe I wasted a day on this thing. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem was my mindset that assumed that every data type would be
>   a general character sequence if not specified and therefore the way to
>   talk to database is through java.lang.String.

I think that's the real issue.

If you specify no type e.g.

`CREATE TABLE mytable (col1,col2,col3)`

Then according to [Determination of Column Affinity(3.1)](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) rule 3:-

> 3) If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no
>   type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.

And then according to Section 3

> A column with affinity BLOB does not prefer one storage class over
>   another and no attempt is made to coerce data from one storage class
>   into another.

I've personally never had an issue with delete. However I do have a tendency to always delete according to rowid.

Here's a working example usage that shows that **`delete`** isn't useless and is deleting according to a long. However the columns are all of type INTEGER :-

```
        int pudeletes;
        int sldeletes;
        int rdeletes;
        int pdeletes;

        if(doesProductExist(productid)) {

            // if not in a transaction then begin a transaction
            if(!intransaction) {
                db.beginTransaction();
            }

            String whereargs[] = { Long.toString(productid)};

            // Delete ProductUsage rows that use this product
            pudeletes = db.delete(
                    DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_TABLE,
                    DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_PRODUCTREF_COL +
                            " = ?",
                    whereargs
            );

            // Delete ShopList rows that use this product
            sldeletes = db.delete(
                    DBShopListTableConstants.SHOPLIST_TABLE,
                    DBShopListTableConstants.SHOPLIST_PRODUCTREF_COL +
                            " = ?",
                    whereargs
            );

            // Delete Rules rows that use this product
            rdeletes = db.delete(
                    DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_TABLE,
                    DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_PRODUCTREF_COL +
                            " = ?",
                    whereargs
            );

            // Delete the Product
            pdeletes = db.delete(
                    DBProductsTableConstants.PRODUCTS_TABLE,
                    DBProductsTableConstants.PRODUCTS_ID_COL +
                            " = ?",
                    whereargs
            );

            // if originally not in a transaction then as one was started
            // complete and end the transaction
            if(!intransaction) {
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
```